# TabView Crash when Selected

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tabview

My app is crashing when I try to select the "inspection" tab I have everything linked Im not sure why I'm getting this error. Can someone lend a hand? Below are my InspectionViewController and my Error Code.

InspectionVC:

```
//
//  InspectionVC.swift
//  Chat
//
//  Created by Wiiliam Pettit on 6/2/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 MVI. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class InspectionVC: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {



    @IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!


    var pickerData: [String] = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        // Connect data:
        self.picker.delegate = self
        self.picker.dataSource = self


        // Input data into the Array:
        pickerData = ["5312", "5387", "53C4", "53W5", "53W8", "5349"]
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return pickerData[row]
    }

    // Catpure the picker view selection
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if(row == 0)
        {
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "http://mvi.crompco.com/Module_Inspect/perform/22243/230")!)
        }
        else if(row == 1)
        {
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "http://mvi.crompco.com")!)
        }
        else if(row == 2)
        {
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "http://mvi.crompco.com")!)
        }
        else if(row == 3)
        {
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "http://mvi.crompco.com")!)
        }
        else if(row == 4)
        {
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "http://mvi.crompco.com")!)
        }
        else if(row == 5)
        {
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "http://mvi.crompco.com")!)
        }
    }



}
```

Error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<QuickChat.InspectionVC 0x7fe83ad275f0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key pickerView.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d443b0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010c545141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d443a59 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010c05ae8b -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 292
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010e369644 -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 87
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010e5d66b9 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d3e9e8d -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 269
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010e5d506f -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1856
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010e36fc73 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 381
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010e370589 -[UIViewController loadView] + 177
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010e3708ba -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 195
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010e37110a -[UIViewController view] + 27
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010e3cd40b -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 476
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010e3cc89c -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:] + 59
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010e3c89d6 -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 410
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010e3c87a5 -[UITabBarController setSelectedViewController:] + 109
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010e3cc741 -[UITabBarController _tabBarItemClicked:] + 384
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010e1cfd22 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010e5e26f7 -[UITabBar _sendAction:withEvent:] + 566
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010e1cfd22 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010e35425c -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010e354577 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
    22  UIKit                               0x000000010e5e4db5 -[UITabBar _buttonUp:] + 113
    23  UIKit                               0x000000010e1cfd22 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    24  UIKit                               0x000000010e35425c -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    25  UIKit                               0x000000010e354577 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
    26  UIKit                               0x000000010e3534b2 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 618
    27  UIKit                               0x000000010e23d49a -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2707
    28  UIKit                               0x000000010e23ebb0 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4114
    29  UIKit                               0x000000010e1eb7b0 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352
    30  UIKit                               0x000000010e9ceadc __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2926
    31  UIKit                               0x000000010e9c6a3a __handleEventQueue + 1122
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d3e9c01 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d3cf0cf __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 527
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d3ce5ff __CFRunLoopRun + 911
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d3ce016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406
    36  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011156ea24 GSEventRunModal + 62
    37  UIKit                               0x000000010e1ce0d4 UIApplicationMain + 159
    38  QuickChat                           0x000000010a83fba7 main + 55
    39  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001104ae65d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: You already set an ibloutlet and then delete it from class but not unbind through xib file

Comment: Make sure you don't have another link to a non existing IBOutlet on the pickerView in your view controller.

Comment: @William You have previously taken "pickerView" as a iboutlet which seems to be change to "picker".so you need to unbind and bind correct iboutlet with "picker".

Answer (score 0):

Your Referencing outlet for the picker is set "pickerView" instead of "picker".

1. Go to storyboard and select the picker view on view controller.
2. Select "Show the connections inspector" in the utilities
   section(right tab of xcode).
3. Remove referencing outlet connected to
   "pickerView".
4. Add referencing outlet to "picker".

Answer (score 0):

Apart of '`picker`' (an IBOutlet of UIPickerView), you have one more outlet connection in your connection inspector.

Open your `Connection Inspector` and remove connection with '`pickerView`' instance.

> Steps: Select Storyboard >> Select View Controller >> Open Connection
>   Inspector >> Check all IBOutlet connections and find 'pickerView' >>
>   Remove connection of 'pickerView'

[image]